# CURLTask abstract method doInBackground(String...) override in AsyncTaskextension does not override?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am throwing to get something from but the is  my asynctask declaration is withing MainActivity.

```
class CURLTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String urlString) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

            return "";
        }
        
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String recvString ) {
        String stnlist =  recvString;
    }
}
```

Creating an instance of CURLtask and calling execute from **onCreate**

```
new CURLTask().execute("someApiUrl.com");
```

Compile Error:

> 

Error:(60, 1) error:
MainActivity.CURLTask is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(String...) in AsyncTask

Also: Hovering mouse over **CURLtask extend AsyncTask**, Android Studio says 
>Class CURLtask must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method doInBackground

And also hovering pointer over the **doInBackground** declaration says:

> Method doInBackground is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `doInBackground` method is declared and used slightly incorrectly.  Should be:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... parms) {
    String urlString = parms[0];
    ...
}
```

Of course, my snippet has no error handling in it, so be sure to check your input parameters accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot...but why is it necessary to make it accept multiple params?

Comment: That's the way the base class is defined, so you must extend and override the method exactly as it is defined.  This allows you to use a single `AsyncTask` to handle multiple inputs (in your example, multiple URLs).  Each `AsyncTask` is used only one time, so this optimization can be leveraged rather than creating multiple `AsyncTask` objects unnecessarily.  Your task could also depend on multiple arguments (all the same type), this variable argument prototype allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `doInBackground` method is declared and used slightly incorrectly.

```
class CURLTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String urlString) {
            try {
                String urlString = parms[0];
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

                return "";
            }

        }



        protected void onPostExecute(String recvString ) {
            String stnlist =  recvString;
        }
    }
```